# Get list of instances matching the intersection of all restriction values

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, graphdb, rdfs

I just started learning how to work with ontologies and make SPARQL queries. I am using a merged copy of these 2 ontologies - [wine](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UCDavisLibrary/wine-ontology/master/ontologies/www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/wine.rdf) and [food](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillord/tawny-owl/master/dev-resources/food.rdf) in GraphDB with OWL-Max ruleset.

I want to get a list of all suitable wines for a given meal. A meal could have a different number of restrictions. I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633364/querying-with-restriction-values-from-an-owl-ontology) and managed to get a list of the active restrictions, but I don't know how to query wines that have all of the values combined.

Is there a way to intersect the wines with the restrictions list result? Should I somehow bind the list values - each property and the corresponding value, so I can query them together or do something like in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396707/sparql-query-on-restriction-list-equivalent-to-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9)?

Definition of the property `hasDrink`, which determines the suitable wines:

```
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="hasDrink">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#MealCourse" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#PotableLiquid" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Example meal:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauceCourse">
<owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="#MealCourse" />
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasFood" />
    <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauce" />
  </owl:Restriction>
</owl:intersectionOf>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasDrink" />
    <owl:allValuesFrom>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasColor" />
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Red" />
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:allValuesFrom>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasDrink" />
    <owl:allValuesFrom>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasBody" />
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Medium" />
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:allValuesFrom>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasDrink" />
    <owl:allValuesFrom>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasFlavor" />
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Moderate" />
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:allValuesFrom>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasDrink" />
    <owl:allValuesFrom>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasSugar" />
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Dry" />
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:allValuesFrom>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

This is my query so far, but the result gives all of the wines which fulfill at least one of the requirements.

```
prefix wine:<http://wine-food.com/project#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT ?w WHERE { 
    ?w a wine:Wine .
    ?w ?p ?val {

       SELECT ?p ?val WHERE { 
           wine:PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauceCourse rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction . 
           ?restriction owl:onProperty wine:hasDrink. 
           ?restriction owl:allValuesFrom [owl:onProperty ?p; owl:hasValue ?val]. 
      } 
   }
}
```

For the given meal, these are the restrictions, which define if a wine is suitable for it.

| p | val |
| --- | --- |
| :hasColor | :Red |
| :hasBody | :Medium |
| :hasFlavor | :Moderate |
| :hasSugar | :Dry |

Comment: you have to use double negation in SPARQL, i.e. "give me all wines where there is no restriction of PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauceCourse that does not exist". For that the pattern is `SELECT { <ALL_WINES PART>  FILTER NOT EXISTS { <ALL_RESTRICTIONS_OF_TARGET_WINE_TYPE> FILTER NOT EXISTS { <THE_WINE_HAS_THE_RESTRICTION>  }}`

Comment: `prefix wine: <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#> 
prefix food: <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/food#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT ?w WHERE { 
    ?w a wine:Wine .
    filter not exists {
       food:PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauceCourse rdfs:subClassOf 
       [owl:onProperty food:hasDrink ;
        owl:allValuesFrom [owl:onProperty ?p; owl:hasValue ?val]
        ] .
       filter not exists {
          ?w ?p ?val 
    }
   }
}`

Comment: that would be the query - note, as you can see I used both prefixes `wine` and `food` because I don't have the merged file. In your case, if you merged all the data into your own namespace, you have to adapt the prefixes in the query. The rest is working for me as expected.

Comment: Output: `wine:MariettaOldVinesRed , wine:WhitehallLaneCabernetFranc , wine:MariettaPetiteSyrah , wine:SaucelitoCanyonZinfandel1998 , wine:PageMillWineryCabernetSauvignon , wine:ChiantiClassico , wine:MariettaZinfandel , wine:MountadamPinotNoir , wine:MariettaCabernetSauvignon , wine:GaryFarrellMerlot , wine:SaucelitoCanyonZinfandel , `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of UninformedUser, the problem has been solved by using the pattern "give me all wines where there is no restriction of PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauceCourse that does not exist" like this:

```
PREFIX wine:<http://wine-food.com/project#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT ?w WHERE { 
    ?w a wine:Wine .
    filter not exists {       
        wine:PastaWithNonSpicyRedSauceCourse rdfs:subClassOf 
                 [owl:onProperty wine:hasDrink ; owl:allValuesFrom [owl:onProperty ?p; owl:hasValue ?val]] .       
        filter not exists {  
            ?w ?p ?val      
        }    
    }
}
```